# What permissions are required to access information_schema.warehouse_load_history from snowsql?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

What permissions are required to access **information_schema.warehouse_load_history** from snowsql? I created a role and user like the below and this shows 0 results.

```
create role TESTROLE;
grant imported privileges on database SNOWFLAKE to role TESTROLE;

create user TEST_USER
LOGIN_NAME = TEST_USER
password = 'Testsnowflake$1234'
default_warehouse = TEST_WH
default_role = TESTROLE
default_namespace = SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
grant role TESTROLE to user TEST_USER;
grant usage on WAREHOUSE TEST_WH to role TESTROLE;
```

Comment: When a user queries an information_schema views it return only the information about the underlying object which this user can access. (tables, schemas, warehouses etc). [Doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema.html#general-usage-notes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see this link for required privileges

```
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/warehouse_load_history.html#usage-notes
```

> To get results from this function, one of the following roles or
> privileges are required:
>
> The ACCOUNTADMIN role can get results from this function as it has all
> of the global account permissions.
>
> A role with the MONITOR USAGE global privilege on the ACCOUNT can
> query this function for any warehouses in the account.
>
> A role with the MONITOR privilege on the WAREHOUSE can query this
> function for the warehouse it has permissions on.
>
> A role with the OWNERSHIP privilege on the WAREHOUSE has all
> permissions on the warehouse including MONITOR.
>
> For more details, see Access Control Privileges.
>
> When calling an Information Schema table function, the session must
> have an INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema in use or the function name must be
> fully-qualified. For more details, see Snowflake Information Schema.